# Grammer Left Factoring

Tags: parsing, ll-grammar

I'm preparing midterm exam, so I found some questions and tried to solve it.
But my answer is not as same as given answer

Question:

```
Consider The Following Grammar, Which Generates Email Addresses:

Addr → Name@Name.id
Name → id | id.Name

This grammar, as written, is not LL(1).  Rewrite the grammar to eliminate all LL(1) conflicts.
```

The question asked us to eliminate LL(1) conflicts
According to my understood, it can be eliminated by left factoring.
Therefore, **my answer** is

```
Addr → Name@Name.id
Name → idName'
Name' → epsilon | .Name
```

However, the **given answer** is

```
Addr → Name@Name.id
Name → idName'
Name' → epsilon | .idName'
```

Is there any wrong of my understood?
Any advise in this post is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, neither your solution nor the one you show as the given answer is LL(1). However, the given answer is a more accurate reflection of the left-factoring procedure. Your solution leaves the artefact `Name -> id Name'`, which now serves no purpose; expanding `Name` in the grammar to its only production eliminates an unnecessary derivation step. (Indeed, you could eliminate both instances of `Name`, the same way.)

But if the question is asking you to come up with an LL(1) grammar, then the given answer is not going to work.

Take a simple address, `me@example.com`, and imagine that the parser runs until just after `example`, which is an `id`. At this point the parser is expecting a `Name'`, which is either empty or something which starts with `.`. (In your grammar, the something is `'.' Name` and in the solution you quote, it's `'.' id Name`, but either way the expected next token is `.`.) So the parser needs to decide between the empty production and the production starting with a `.`. Since the lookahead is `.`, the parser could certainly choose the production starting with `.`. But what about choosing the empty production? In that case, the next token will match whatever follows the second `Name` in `Addr -> Name @ Name . id`, which is also a `.`. In other words, looking at the `.`, the parser has two apparently valid options: the empty production or the production starting with `.`. And that's true whether it's using your grammar or the solution's grammar.

The simplest solution (which is not very general) is to rearrange the `Addr` rule. `Addr` wants there to be at least two `id`s after the `@`, which could just as well be achieved with:

```
Addr -> Name @ id . Name
```

You still need to left-factor `Name` to make that work, but now there is no problem with `Name`'s FOLLOW set; it can no longer be followed by a `.`, and the decision after `example` is forced.